# Visa requirements for a 2-week holiday to Canada

Tags: canada, tourist-visas, turkish-citizens

I am a Turkish citizen married to a British citizen living in the UK. I have an indefinite leave to remain residency permit. What documents do I need for a 2-week holiday to Canada?

Answer (score 1):

The Canadian Immigration and Citizenship has a web page questionnaire "Do I need a visa to go to Canada", according to which you do need a visa.

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp